# CherryPy Memory Usage: Mac vs Ubuntu

Tags: cherrypy

I am deploying a fairly heavy app through `cherrypy` (15.0.0). I am developing it on MacOS (anaconda python2.7.15) and deploying it on Ubuntu 18.04LTS (python 2.7.15c1). The differences in memory handling I am observing through `htop` are confusing me, though:

- **Mac**: 108G (VIRT), 2700M (RES) and only one thread visible
- **Ubuntu**: 8888M (VIRT), 4758M (RES) and more than 60 visible threads (most are dormant).

I would like to get Mac-like memory usage on deployment, but can't figure out what is causing the huge difference...